# Error while creating web service client using Apache Axis 2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have been trying to create a web service client using Apache Axis 2. I have used axis2- 1.0.jar. I am also using Axiom-api, Axiom-impl, Axis2-transport & Axis kernel jars. I am getting 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/om/OMContainer' while creating object of ServiceClient class. I am not able to find the class mentioned anywhere in the internet. Can any one help on this please? I have been using Spring, JBoss 5.1 and Java 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.ws.commons.om.OMContainer` is available inside the `axiom-api.jar`. It is little bit unclear that how you are creating the client but assuming that you are generating client stub, check whether that package is available in your class path when you are generating the client. If you are using maven, dependencies will be automatically get added.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.commons.axiom

P:S: Make sure all of the related Axis2 libraries are in the class path before generating the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Broken axis2-kernel.jar caused this problem. Anyway, thank you!